# iOS coredata predicate within relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a table like:

POI (= point of Interest) --> belongsToCategory --> POICategory

Now I want basically a query like:
"Give me all POIs which belong to category x, y, z...."
The number of categories I query can of course be anything. So my questions are:

1. How can I query for an unlimited amount of predicates?
2. I want to store the query (if possible) within the user defaults. However on what should I build the query on then? I wanted to do it directly on the managed object but I guess this won't work. And the name isn't safe as well, since the category name could be changed
3. How do I store this predicate in the users defaults?

Comment: `predicateFormat` can help you saving the `NSPredicate` into a `NSString`. You can aggregate `NSPredicate` (look at `NSCompoundPredicate`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `POI` is an entity which has a relationship named `belongsToCategory`, with `POICategory` as its destination entity.  You don't say whether that relationship is to-one or to-many (the predicate differs slightly in each case).  If you have an array `requiredCategories` containing the `POICategory` objects (x, y, z, etc) that you are interested in, then you can use the `IN` operator in the predicate, like this:

For to-one:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"POI"];
fetch.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"belongsToCategory IN %@",requiredCategories];
NSError *error = nil;
[context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
... etc
```

For to-many:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"POI"];
fetch.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY belongsToCategory IN %@",requiredCategories];
NSError *error = nil;
[context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
... etc
```

The `IN` operator avoids having to build a compound predicate from separate predicates for each category.

As regards storing the query in `NSUserDefaults`, I guess you want to keep details of the required categories (x, y, z, etc) so that you can rebuild the query some time subsequently.  It can be done, but my recommendation would be: don't.  Keeping details of `NSManagedObjects` in `NSUserDefaults` is a square peg in a round hole.  Better to design your CoreData entities in such a way as to keep track of which categories have been selected (e.g. add a `selected` attribute to the `POICategory`).

Comment: Yeah sorry my mistake. A POI can only have one category in my app. But you've pointed me to the correct hints, especially the selected attribute is really nice! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to make the query in POICategory table with predicate of all categories you need and then read the set of  POI simply accessing poiCategory.poiArray

I also suggested to make a category on NSPredicate to construct the predicates you need. Saving in userdefaults will force you to mantain it if changes needed